# Loop a static value in Jmeter http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have **enums** called `MALE`, `FEMALE`, `OTHERS` which needs to be send to my http request by looping it.

Scenario is when jmeter script runs, a http request will take the value MALE another thread can take the value as FEMALE and continues. This is important because every ENUM value reaches to different section of the backend system.

I would love hear a help.

[image]

you can see in the above body entity type needs to be changed to all the enums types.

Comment: What did you try? Did you try CSV data set config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people go for [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for this, however if for some reason you cannot or don't want to have external data files you can:

1. Declare your ENUM values under i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element:

   [image]
2. Use [__RandomFromMultipleVars() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars) to select a random value from them:

   ```
   ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(MALE|FEMALE|OTHERS,)}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Works like charm. I used 2. to implement. Thank you @Dmitri T